# Decrypt and run Jar without saving it on the disk?

Tags: java, encryption, authentication

I am working on a login system for my Java application and want to encrypt the program with RSA (or something similar). Then when someone logs in, it will decrypt the file in memory and run it in memory, instead of decrypting and saving it decrypted on the disk.

Is this possible or should I use another way?

Comment: Why would the program (jar) need to be encrypted?  How would a user access the system?

Comment: Whatever encryption you use, people will be able to examine the binary that does the decryption and thus will be able to mimic it.

Comment: You could decrypt the file, execute it, and then delete after you used it